# how do I set the right view on my controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

I was able to insert data through jquery ajax using modal but the problem is i get a different view

This is my AjaxCrudController

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    //
    $create = Post::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($create);
}
```

I want to view the page were my table is to see my added post it's on my ajax-crud-2.blade.php how do i get to this view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following,

Define Route:

```
Route::get('ajax/crud/2','AjaxCrudController@getAjaxCrud2');
```

Make function:

```
public function getAjaxCrud2(){
     $data = Post::all();
     return view('ajax-crud-2',compact('data'));
}
```

Now, when ajax call returns success then you have to redirect to route `ajax/crud/2`.

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $create = Post::create($request->all());
        //return response()->json($create);
        //return view('ajax-crud-2')->json('$create');

        //return view()->json('$create');
        return redirect('ajax/crud/2')->json($create);
         
    }

Comment: is it return redirect('ajax/crud/2')->json($create);

Comment: On your success function in ajax,
`success:function (data) {
                    if(data.create==true){
window.location = base_url+"/ajax/crud/2";
                    }
                }`

Comment: This will redirect to `ajax/crud/2` on successful insertion where you will see your records

Comment: this will reload the page it was supposed to be realtime

Comment: Then you might have cache problems, try `php artisan view:cache`

Comment: aw it says on my cmd view cache is not defined